# Can my Passive Perception/Investigation skills be higher than my Active?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

The feat "Observant" states that when this feat is taken, the player's passive perception/intelligence increase by 5

> ### Observant
>
> [...]
>
> - You have a +5 bonus to your passive Wisdom (Perception) and passive Intelligence (Investigation) scores. 
>     These "Passive" skills are used when you are just being generally observant, not when you are actively searching for something.

However, when proficiency is taken in a skill, you only start with a +2 bonus, so if you are actively trying to search for something, you only get the +2 proficiency. Is that correct? To me, this seems a bit... unbalanced. Is this right?

Comment: The wording is still a little strange - are you under the impression that you only get a +2 to skills you are proficient and nothing else, or do you know that you is a +2 on top if the ability score modifier for the skill?

Comment: If this seems imbalanced to you, consider what bonuses would other feats confer if chosen in place of Observant (eg. completely new actions or bonus actions, spellcasting ability). This is a high bonus, but commensurate.

Answer (score 2):

It's not strictly higher, just higher on average. By default, your passive perception equals 10 + any modifiers you'd add to the roll. With the feat, you instead get 15 + any modifiers. However, when rolling, you could still roll 16-20, making the result higher. This feat just makes you more aware when you're not actively trying to look out for something.